# multiple vars via url question

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a method

```
function checkin($var1){

$newVar1 = $var1;
....
...
}
```

I am calling it via Restful and I am passing it like this

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/controller/checkin/'.$var1;
```

Now i want to pass two variables but I am not sure how would it pick the second one
I guess I can do this

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/controller/checkin/'.$var1.'/'.$var2;
```

not sure what would I do on receiving end to make sure it knows what var to use where.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the other end, you have to change your action method signature to

```
function checkin($var1, $var2){
    // (...)
}
```

Another option is using Cake's named parameters. That would require a change in both the url and the action:

**URL**

```
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/controller/checkin/var1:'.$var1.'/var2:'.$var2;
```

**Action method**

```
function checkin(){
    $var1 = $this->params['named']['var1'];
    $var2 = $this->params['named']['var2'];
}
```